# При подключении по cURL получаю ошибку error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Tags: php, curl, ssl

Я хочу понимать есть ли сертификат на домене или нет. Подключаюсь я так:

```
$curlInit = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_exec($curlInit);
curl_errno($curlInit);
curl_error($curlInit);
curl_close($curlInit);
```

Проблема в том, что на доменах сертификат есть и он действителен и я не понимаю почему получаю такую ошибку. Помогите ее решить.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curlInit, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`. Если не устраивает - для начала (можно в консоли), посмотрите `echo ini_get('curl.cainfo') . PHP_EOL; echo ini_get('openssl.cafile') .PHP_EOL;`

Comment: С чего вы взяли что он действителен, если ПО говорит об обратном? Где доказательства или проверка на его действительность? И если вы правы, то как уверены в том что он действителен? Может, стоит подсказать ПО что делать когда оно проверяет сертификат?